Apart from Recurrent Neural Networks what are some alternatives to AR(n), ARIMA(p,q) models?
I want to write a master thesis in CS (Machine learning). The topic that was assigned to me was time series prediction. I want to compare different ML methods with statistical methods (AR,ARIMA). I am not interested in RNN as other students (5 people are doing this topic) will do that and I want to choose something different. All the literature I found has to do with RNNs are there the only ML method. I understand there are highly performing but are there other methods? I want to use retail prices to predict unemployment of using extreme weather events to predict economic losses in a region.

Welcome to Cross Validated! What kind of time series prediction do you mean? For instance, speech recognition could be seen as time series prediction: I input a time series of my voice, and Siri predicts that I want to listen to Anti-Hero. I see that as different, at least potentially, from seeing a time series of daily high temperatures and trying to predict the temperature when you want to have your pool party or go skiing over the weekend.

Lets say using retail prices to predict unemployment of using extreme weather events to predict economic losses in a region.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
